# (Javascript) How to extract the last part of the current URL - without the file extension?

Tags: javascript, url, location, extract

I currently have the following javascript code working:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    urlPath=window.location.pathname; 
    urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 
    urlPath1=urlPathArray[2]; 
    document.write('<a href="http://www.example.com/contact.php?id='+urlPath1+'">test</a>'); 
    </script>
```

Lets say the current URL is `http://www.example.com/products/0033.htm`

The javascript produces a hyperlink to `http://www.example.com/contact.php?id=0033.htm`

How do I modify this script so that *urlPath1* and the eventual hyperlink is without the ".htm" part?

Comment: Is the file extention any size or only `.htm`? Because you could just use a substring

Comment: `urlPathArray[2];` Use `urlPathArray[urlPathArray.length - 1]` to get the last element...

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what you did to get the filename, but split on `.` instead of `/` and take the first piece.

Comment: It may not work, because the first piece would be `/products/0033` instead of 0033. `location.pathname` returns the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname,
    urlPathArray = urlPath.split('.'),
    urlPath1 = urlPathArray[0].split('/').pop(); 

document.write('<a href="http://www.example.com/contact.php?id='+urlPath1+'">test</a>');
```

Comment: Dots can be in the middle of the pathname.  You need to isolate the last segment of the path and then remove any extension that might be there.

Comment: Hi Grace, thanks for your quick response.  I tried your example but it does not seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Update: I solved it using the following modified code:

`urlPath=window.location.pathname; 
urlPathArray = urlPath.split('/'); 
urlPath1=urlPathArray[urlPathArray.length - 1]; 
urlPath2= urlPath1.split('.');
productID=urlPath2[0];

document.write('<a href="http://www.example.com/contact.php?id='+productID+'">test</a>'); `

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Glad that you fixed it by yourself! :)

Comment: if you answer your own question you should respond as an answer and choose that as 'correct' it is encouraged by Stack Overflow as it helps direct other people to the answer  
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer